# Sort coordinates of quad polygon

Tags: objective-c, c, polygon

I am trying to sort the coordinates of a quad polygon.

The polygon is roughly a rectangle but it is NOT a perfect rectangle.

An example is below:

[image]

All I get from this polygon is a sets of 4 coordinates, and I want to sort it as clockwise everytime i receive it. And first point must always be the top left.

Any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: Does it matter which coordinate comes first? Or as long as it's clockwise, the first point can be any (top, bottom-right, etc)

Comment: The first must always be top right.

Comment: What if there are 2 points which are equally at the top right? Like the `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` of a square rotated 45 degrees? Is the top or the right more important?

Comment: the shape will always be "rectangular" -ish. the btmLeft will not go above topright. and so on.

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you had a rectangle like this: `◊` (pretend its regular), then which side comes first? The top or the right?

Comment: It won't be like that, ever.

Comment: You can calculate the center of your polygon (where diagonals are crossing) and compute relative coordinates of vertices then compute angles. The top-right corner will be the Easting and Northing maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question again. Assuming we have an array of points of the quad. And the origin point (0,0) is at most top left. The order is arbitrary. Here i simply put in the points.

```
NSMutableArray *pointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rf.bottomLeft],
                                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rf.topRight],
                                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rf.topLeft],
                                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rf.bottomRight],
                                 nil];
```

First, we sort the points by x coordinates from small to big.

```
    NSArray *sortedByX = [pointsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *obj1, NSValue *obj2) {
        CGPoint p1 = [obj1 CGPointValue];
        CGPoint p2 = [obj2 CGPointValue];
        return p1.x > p2.x;
    }];
```

Then we get the first 2 points (these two basically the top left and bottom left). So we check the Y values of these two to determine which is at top and which is at bottom, and we can assign that immediately.

```
    CGPoint Pt1, Pt2, Pt3, Pt4;

    CGPoint ptMinX1 = [[sortedByX objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint ptMinX2 = [[sortedByX objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];

    if (ptMinX1.y<ptMinX2.y) {
        Pt1 = ptMinX1;
        Pt4 = ptMinX2;
    } else {
        Pt1 = ptMinX2;
        Pt4 = ptMinX1;
    }
```

Same is done to determine the right sides points.

```
    CGPoint ptMaxX1 = [[sortedByX objectAtIndex:2] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint ptMaxX2 = [[sortedByX objectAtIndex:3] CGPointValue];

    if (ptMaxX1.y<ptMaxX2.y) {
        Pt2 = ptMaxX1;
        Pt3 = ptMaxX2;
    } else {
        Pt3 = ptMaxX1;
        Pt2 = ptMaxX2;
    }
```

Finally we get the Points in that order, clockwise:

```
// Pt1   Pt2
//
// Pt4   Pt3
```

You can then arrange these points as you like (anticlockwise, zig zag or whatever)

Comment: How your coordinates are defined (x=0 & y=0) at the left bottom corner ? In that case, I obtain a non-clockwise order when following your formula.

Comment: actually in my system, the origin (0,0) is at top left.

Comment: Could you add your assumption relative to the origin in your answer ?